# ASP.NET HttpHandler access granting from web.config

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I am adding httpHandler in `<httpHandlers>`:

```
<httpHandlers>
  <add verb="*" path="someHandlerPath.ashx" type="Web.Framework.HttpHandlers.SomeHandler, Web.Framework, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral" />
</httpHandlers>
```

Further, I want to grant access to all users in `<location>`:

```
<location path="someHandlerPath.ashx">
  <system.web>
      <authorization>
          <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
  </system.web></location>
```

But this is not working!
How can I also grant access to all users?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you be more specific about what "this is not working" means? Is your handler only accessible to authenticated users, or to nobody?

Comment: Only to authenticated users, location -> path isn't work, because this path isn't present in solution directory, it's added virtually in httpHandlers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, the problem was in our web.framework.
My apologies for taking your time! Thanks!

Comment: Is the problem something you think others might have, or is it very specific to something custom-built you have? It it's the former, you might want to update your answer to have the actual solution to the problem so that anyone else having the same thing will get help.

Answer (score 0):

The information given is not complete. 
However in the example you didn't close the location tag.
Try writing this:

```
<location path="someHandlerPath.ashx">
  <system.web>
      <authorization>
          <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

Also make sure to put it outside the system.web tag.

Comment: Sorry, some problem with visualization, location tag was closed and outside system.web tag.